# Use a bound service vs create a new thread in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service

I suppose the main selling point of started service is that it can outlive an application itself to do something like downloading a lot of data.

What about a bound service compared to a new thread? A bound service lives until it's completely unbind which is as long as the application runs in my understanding. Why not just start a new thread instead e.g. to handle Bluetooth connection and data transfer?

The motivation behind my question is that I'm reading the code of the BluetoothHDP sample and the use of a bound service there confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service you want to use when you want to do something non UI specific and not UI dependent. Starting a thread in UI is still UI dependent since your main thread becomes it parent. If you rotate device all threads get destroyed, however servie can continue to run. thats y for Bluetooth you would have service. similar case for lets say voice recording.

Comment: If you bind to a service, it is also destroyed when the activity binding to it gets destroyed because of the rotation.

Comment: It's easy to control that to prevent service to finish if it has any running tasks. You can keep it in foreground mode and allow activity to bind to it. Think of the music app on device where the activity binds to music service, but the service keeps running as long as the song is being played

Comment: Yes, but in that case it's also a started service (because it lives after the last unbind), not a simple local bound service, as the question asks.